# Grails configuration ConfigSlurper

Tags: grails, groovy

I want to separate config files into few small parts. In `Config.groovy` I have defined `grails.config.locations` array to point these files:

```
grails.config.locations = [
    "classpath:config.properties",
    "classpath:some-config.groovy",
]
```

And then I am checking configuration map by accessing: `grailsApplication.config`

The first configuration file is Java properties file, which loads properly:

*config.properties*

```
grails.serverURL=http://localhost:8080/selly
..
```

The second one is `.groovy` file which in reference to the documentation (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized) should be loaded from automatically parsed `ConfigSlurper` file format:

*some-config.groovy:*

```
app {
    testvar {
        foo = true
    }
}
```

But `grailsApplication.config.app` does not exists (no field in debug and `println` returns empty map `[:]`).

Can anyone give an example of loading groovy files?

Files are placed in: `grails-app\conf\`, for example `grails-app\conf\config.properties`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've configured both files correctly. `grailsApplication.config.app` might be null simply because it is not a leaf node, have you tried `grailsApplication.config.app.testvar.foo`?

Comment: Howdy @Dónal. Yes, I have tried `grailsApplication.config.app.testvar.foo`, but it is also empty map `[:]`. The trailing comma doesn't matter (http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1015-Collections).

Comment: @Athlan thanks for the link, I didn't know trailing commas are officially permitted. I'm not sure why this isn't working, could you workaround the problem by converting the `.groovy` config file to a `.properties` file?